# Remove-AzureStorageBlob not working in runbook

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage

Why does the following powershell-code work perfectly well on my local machine but fails when executing it in an Azure Automation runbook?

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container "workloads" -Prefix "aaa" | Remove-AzureStorageBlob
```

**Runbook-Error-Message**

```
Remove-AzureStorageBlob : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command 
does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline 
input.
At Remove-CID:116 char:116
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Windo...zureStorageBlob:PSObject) [Remove-AzureStorageBlob],  ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.RemoveStorageAzureBlobCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Unwieldy, but it works

```
$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $container -Prefix "aaa"

foreach($blob in $blobs)
{
    Remove-AzureStorageBlob -Blob $blob.Name -Container $container
}
```

Found [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Remove-Storage-Blobs-that-aae4b761).